# I turned all windows invisible in KDE neon

Tags: kde, system-settings

I accidentally forced all windows to be invisible in window rules setting. I literally can't see any window including browser, settings and any other app. How do I reset settings without even seeing the console? I BEG FOR HELP, PLEASE

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Kubuntu is on-topic here being a flavor, KDE Neon however isn't sorry, but you'll likely have to fix the issue in CLI; I'd search for files altered around the date/time you changed the setting, and reverse that way; or restore that file from backups if you're unsure...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete everything at `~/.config/KDE` (ether in uppercase or lowercase) and also remove configuration at `~/.config/kwinrc`. If still your problem presist then again create `~/.config/kwinrc` and add `NoPlugin=true`